# Sending data from API Gateway to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Goal: Get real-time stock data from [IEX API](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#introduction), store it in DynamoDB, use data in DynamoDB to display on site.

Edit: I want to use the pull mechanism from the API where I can pull data periodically.

Currently, on API gateway, I created a get method for my stocks resource where I set the integration type to HTTP and entered the IEX Endpoint URL as the Endpoint URL. For now, I just got the data for one stock and the JSON Response Body looks like:

```
{
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "companyName": "Apple Inc",
  "primaryExchange": "NASDAQ/NGS (GLOBAL SELECT MARKET)",
  "calculationPrice": "close",
  "open": 132.5,
  "openTime": 1610116201607,
  "openSource": "official",
  "close": 132.05,
  "closeTime": 1610139600449,
  "closeSource": "official"
}
```

I want to integrate Lambda here somehow so that it can get this API data and store it in DynamoDB. So far this is what my Lambda function looks like:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    
    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;
    
    const { symbol, companyName } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    
    const params = {
        TableName: "Stocks",
        Item: {
            symbol: symbol,
            companyName: companyName
        }
    };
    
    try {
        const data = await documentClient.put(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
        statusCode = 201;
        
    } catch(err) {
        responseBody = `Unable to put product: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;
    }
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: responseBody
    };
    
    return response
};
```

How do I get the API data from API Gateway and integrate it with a Lambda function that stores this data to DynamoDB?

Comment: which process will be calling the stock api and how frequently? If you just want to call stock api and pull data every few minutes, you just need is a Lambda that does both calling stock api and writing to DynamoDB. You can trigger the Lambda from Cloudwatch

Comment: And which IEX APIs are you planning to use?  Looks like they provide both a pull model where you can either call IEX periodically to get updated data, and a push model where they stream data to you as updates become available; this question needs to be narrowed down a bit before it can be answered

Comment: @MikeDinescu I want to pull data periodically